# Old paths still appearing after resizing vector image, is this normal

Tags: adobe-illustrator

New to graphics and trying to work through this but unable to find info despite many searches.

Old paths are still appearing or I should say they are in the original position after resizing vector image, is this normal and how would I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE ! It is really hard to say what is going on for you without some more information. Can you add some screenshots of what is happening ? Please explain what exactly it is you are resizing and explain further how you are doing the resizing ? (are you scaling, or dragging a corner of the bounding box, or using the transform panel, etc. ?) With the info you have given best bet would be you are scaling a copy of the original and the original remains where it started.

Comment: Is it possible that some layers are locked?

Comment: Is it possible you held down the Option/Alt key when resizing?? (There's not much information here to go on)

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to go on here, this could fit your problem description though:

Did you use the **transform** tool from the Appearance Panel in Illustrator to scale your object? This can results in the situation you have described.

**This object is scaled using the scale command:**

[image: object scaled using the the scale command]

**This object is scaled using the transform command from the appearance window:**

[image: object scaled using the transform command]

As you can see, the actual paths are smaller than the appearing outline.
The *transform* properties are more like an *"effect"* that alters the appearance of the object than an actual modification of its properties.

While this seems to only add to the complexity/confusion of working with Illustrator, it can be quite useful. ;)

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply.  Yes, I used transform/scale, as in your example above,  thanks for the comments.  Any idea how I make the path fix the outline?

Comment: sure, you can just hit 'Object' / 'Expand' then the "Effect" will be applied to the actual Path.

Comment: Ahhh awesome, that done the trick, lots to learn, thanks heaps.